# Get Task Name only from SCHTASKS /query through bat file

Tags: batch-file

I need t get only task name instead of TaskName, NextRuntime, Status from **SCHTASKS /query** query, how can i do the same?

Comment: May be this Can give you an Idea http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('schtasks /query /fo list^|findstr /b "Aufgabenname"') do @echo %%b
```

Replace "Aufgabenname" with the corresponding term in your language ("TaskName" in English)
If you need the taskname without path, use `echo %%~nxb`
For use directly at command line, replace every `%%` with `%` only.